# Adding microdata to Concrete5 through a content editor

Tags: html, microdata, concrete5, tinymce-4

TinyMCE strips certain microdata from content entries when added to the html.  I'm building a website for a mobile spa service, and would like to list their services as products using schema.org's markup.  So my question is this: Is there a wysiwyg editor block I can let my client use that wont "clean" microdata I end up putting in later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but depending on how structured the content is, you might consider creating a new block type using Designer Content and then wrap individual fields with microdata tags.

http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/designer-content/

Comment: The issue with that is that I have photos interspersed through the content, some on the left, some on the right. I don't think I could accomplish this using designer-content could css solve this?

Comment: yeah, I guess it depends on your content. if the placement of images can be somewhat structured, then it seems like you could use designer-content.

Comment: While it doesn't solve my problem It does answer my question.